# focus on input causes keyboard to act strangely

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, input

I am trying to use .focus() to focus on the input and then automatically call the keyboard to show up, every time when the page changes. Here are my codes:

jquery:

```
  $(questionPage).on("pageshow",function(){
    $('input').focus();
  });
```

HTML5:

```
   <input type="email" name="text_email" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px" placeholder=""value="" class="email"'/> ;
```

But every time when the page changes, the keyboard shows up and closes immediately. Anyone have any idea what is causing it? Any tips on how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried focussing after a short delay, say 50ms?

Comment: Specify which page you want this event to fire. `'pageshow', '#pageId', function()`

Comment: @robertc  I tried with $('input').focus().delay(5000); and setTimeout(function() {$('input').focus();}, 5000); unfortunately none of them working :(

Comment: @Omar I have already $(questionPage) as an ID

Comment: I said after a short delay

Comment: then try `$(document).on('pageshow', '#pageID', function() {...});`

Comment: @robertc Thank you very much. I have already solved the problem. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Omar Thanks a lot. It is just because the event is  triggered many times. Multiple event triggering is a constant problem in jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problems. It is because that the events will be triggered multiple times. According to [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events) on Prevent multiple event binding/triggering. I solved the problems with the following codes:

```
$(questionPage).on("pageshow",function(){
    $('textarea').focus();
    $('input').focus().delay(5000);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```